# get word document

Tags: c#

I have a directory which have a few word documents (.doc) files. I want to get each one from that directory and put them into a list so I can open them. How do I loop through to get them and once I get them how do I open them.

Comment: Documentation available at MSDN with code sample, for you to review and learn from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Comment: Take a look at the following: System.IO.Directory, foreach and System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.  Hope this is enough to get you started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list all the word documents in a directory:

```
using System.IO;

    DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Test");
    FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FI.FullName); 
        }
```

And then just a quick way to open the word documents:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

    Process.Start(@"C:\Path to File\File.doc");
```